# Laravel custom auth with custom field names

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have problem with a project which primary database is MsSql and tables and fields look like that:

**GetCustomers** 
 - Username 
 - Pasword 
 - ......

What I need is set Laravel auth to this mssql database and set primary field Username and Password for auth.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to be very clear with your question and include as much detail as possible with relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a property in **app/Http/AuthController.php**

`protected $username = 'username';`

source: http://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-with-username-instead-of-email/

Answer (score 0):

Change function in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` regarding your needs.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'Username';
}
```

with this you will override `username()` function in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`

Laravel uses this function to determine credentials in validation, at login attempt.

This works perfectly in Laravel version 5.4+

Comment: thank you. And where i found file for change primary table name from ,, users ,, to ,, Get_Customers ,,

Comment: @pribor app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php ... first line in my answer :) What is your Laravel version?

Comment: thanks. v5.5 . but not working for me because i try connect to mssql with created tables and fields and my goal will be set laravel auth to mssql database :(