# Laravel Auth with only one model field/column

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

i want to know how i can use only one column of a table to make Authentication in laravel.

example: suppose we have a USER Model that's mean we have USERS table, i don't want to use USERNAME and PASSOWORD to do login, but instead of that i want to use just ONE FIELD/COLUMN named for example AuthKey.

i made some research and also made some change in Model for example change fillable and hidden but won't work or i don't know how to use it correctly.

and thanks in advance, i really appreciate that!

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain the precise error / problem. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: as i said i tried a change fillable and hidden but no solution, i find that in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550584/laravel-custom-auth-with-custom-field-names)

Comment: Sorry but a vague description doesn't tell us anything. We've got no code, no error messages, and no clear problem description. Are we supposed to simply guess exactly what is going wrong in your code, do you imagine? Obviously, that is not a productive use of anyone's time. We need a [mre] of the issue. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: The `fillable` and `hidden` properties of a `User.php` Model in Laravel have next-to-nothing to do with Authentication... Those are used for "mass assignment" and hiding/showing attributes when the model is converted to JSON/an array... Please read the documentation for Authentication in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication, specifically how the "Credentials" work when authenticating: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#authenticating-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you want to make Authentication by using one column is **a vary bad idea** however I will tell you how to make it.

Step one: **Modify users table**

In your users table you will have a column called for example **auth_key**

Step two: **Register the user**

I don't know how users will register in your application but the **auth_key** must be unique so you have to use something like **uniqid()** function so users may be registered like this:

```
User::create([
   'username' => 'test',
   'auth_key' => uniqid(), // You may add the username before it if exists like this 'test' . uniqid()
   'other_field' => 'other_field'
]);
```

Step three: **Login the user**

Your login code should be something like this:

```
$user = User::where('auth_key',$request->auth_key)->first();
if($user){
  auth()->login($user);
  return redirect()->route('your_route_here');
}
// Here the user doesn't exist so you should flash some error messages here and return back
return back();
```

Comment: yes it's bad thing to do authentication with only one column but that it's just to search not to use it in real apps